# HTTPS not sending some auth headers with Retrofit

Tags: android, retrofit, android-networking, okhttp

I am using Retrofit for web requests on my android library. Strangely, if I use HTTPS `some` of the web requests fail with 403 and the others pass - and the failure message is  {"detail": "Authentication credentials were not provided."}
Seems like somehow when I do HTTPS for some of the web requests my authtoken is not being passed

```
05-09 13:47:10.110    6850-6890/com.gmspartnersltd.earthmiles.debug D/Retrofit﹕ <--- HTTP 200 http://staging.earthmiles.co.uk/api/v1/accounts/profile/firstupdate/2419/ (1187ms)
05-09 13:47:10.513    6850-6890/com.gmspartnersltd.earthmiles.debug D/Retrofit﹕ <--- HTTP 200 http://staging.earthmiles.co.uk/api/v1/globalprefs/connectedapps/ (213ms)
05-09 13:47:12.045    6850-6890/com.gmspartnersltd.earthmiles.debug D/Retrofit﹕ <--- HTTP 200 http://staging.earthmiles.co.uk/api/v1/rewards/rewards?page=1 (408ms)
05-09 13:47:12.354    6850-6962/com.gmspartnersltd.earthmiles.debug D/Retrofit﹕ <--- HTTP 200 http://staging.earthmiles.co.uk/api/v1/accounts/profile/me/ (686ms)
05-09 13:47:12.969    6850-6964/com.gmspartnersltd.earthmiles.debug D/Retrofit﹕ <--- HTTP 200 http://staging.earthmiles.co.uk/api/v1/feeds/feeds?page=1&segment_type=content (1279ms)
05-09 13:47:13.079    6850-6965/com.gmspartnersltd.earthmiles.debug D/Retrofit﹕ <--- HTTP 200 http://staging.earthmiles.co.uk/api/v1/feeds/feeds?page=1&segment_type=friends (1366ms)
05-09 13:47:13.405    6850-6890/com.gmspartnersltd.earthmiles.debug D/Retrofit﹕ <--- HTTP 200 http://staging.earthmiles.co.uk/api/v1/rewards/rewards?page=2 (1155ms)
05-09 13:48:03.584    7053-7094/com.gmspartnersltd.earthmiles.debug D/Retrofit﹕ <--- HTTP 200 https://staging.earthmiles.co.uk/api/v1/globalprefs/iosapppreferences/1/ (262ms)
05-09 13:48:10.731    7053-7094/com.gmspartnersltd.earthmiles.debug D/Retrofit﹕ <--- HTTP 200 https://staging.earthmiles.co.uk/api/v1/accounts/checkuserwithemail/?email=test295%40xyz.com (114ms)
05-09 13:48:12.528    7053-7094/com.gmspartnersltd.earthmiles.debug D/Retrofit﹕ <--- HTTP 201 https://staging.earthmiles.co.uk/api/v1/accounts/register/ (198ms)
05-09 13:48:13.375    7053-7094/com.gmspartnersltd.earthmiles.debug D/Retrofit﹕ <--- HTTP 200 https://staging.earthmiles.co.uk/api/v1/accounts/profile/firstupdate/2420/ (800ms)
05-09 13:48:13.801    7053-7094/com.gmspartnersltd.earthmiles.debug D/Retrofit﹕ <--- HTTP 200 https://staging.earthmiles.co.uk/api/v1/globalprefs/connectedapps/ (200ms)
05-09 13:48:15.578    7053-7168/com.gmspartnersltd.earthmiles.debug D/Retrofit﹕ <--- HTTP 200 https://staging.earthmiles.co.uk/api/v1/accounts/profile/me/ (349ms)
05-09 13:48:15.617    7053-7094/com.gmspartnersltd.earthmiles.debug D/Retrofit﹕ <--- HTTP 403 https://staging.earthmiles.co.uk/api/v1/rewards/rewards?page=1 (424ms)
05-09 13:48:15.692    7053-7169/com.gmspartnersltd.earthmiles.debug D/Retrofit﹕ <--- HTTP 403 https://staging.earthmiles.co.uk/api/v1/feeds/feeds?page=1&segment_type=content (442ms)
05-09 13:48:15.734    7053-7170/com.gmspartnersltd.earthmiles.debug D/Retrofit﹕ <--- HTTP 403 https://staging.earthmiles.co.uk/api/v1/feeds/feeds?page=1&segment_type=friends (449ms)
```

### Request

```
05-09 13:47:11.713    6850-6965/com.gmspartnersltd.earthmiles.debug D/Retrofit﹕ ---> HTTP GET http://staging.earthmiles.co.uk/api/v1/feeds/feeds?page=1&segment_type=friends
05-09 13:47:11.713    6850-6965/com.gmspartnersltd.earthmiles.debug D/Retrofit﹕ Screen-Width: 1080
05-09 13:47:11.713    6850-6965/com.gmspartnersltd.earthmiles.debug D/Retrofit﹕ Screen-Height: 1776
05-09 13:47:11.713    6850-6965/com.gmspartnersltd.earthmiles.debug D/Retrofit﹕ Screen-Density: 3.0
05-09 13:47:11.713    6850-6965/com.gmspartnersltd.earthmiles.debug D/Retrofit﹕ Screen-Scaled-Density: 3.0
05-09 13:47:11.713    6850-6965/com.gmspartnersltd.earthmiles.debug D/Retrofit﹕ Screen-Density-DPI: 480
05-09 13:47:11.713    6850-6965/com.gmspartnersltd.earthmiles.debug D/Retrofit﹕ Device-Type: android
05-09 13:47:11.713    6850-6965/com.gmspartnersltd.earthmiles.debug D/Retrofit﹕ App-Version: 1.0
05-09 13:47:11.713    6850-6965/com.gmspartnersltd.earthmiles.debug D/Retrofit﹕ Authorization: Token 1f125a32123fe8c465bd16f30e1a21064c144c7b           
05-09 13:47:11.713    6850-6965/com.gmspartnersltd.earthmiles.debug D/Retrofit﹕ ---> END HTTP (no body)
```

When I use this authtoken in Postmand, I get a valid response from my server

### Response

```
05-09 13:48:15.734    7053-7170/com.gmspartnersltd.earthmiles.debug D/Retrofit﹕ <--- HTTP 403 https://staging.earthmiles.co.uk/api/v1/feeds/feeds?page=1&segment_type=friends (449ms)
05-09 13:48:15.734    7053-7170/com.gmspartnersltd.earthmiles.debug D/Retrofit﹕ Server: nginx/1.4.6 (Ubuntu)
05-09 13:48:15.734    7053-7170/com.gmspartnersltd.earthmiles.debug D/Retrofit﹕ Date: Sat, 09 May 2015 17:48:44 GMT
05-09 13:48:15.734    7053-7170/com.gmspartnersltd.earthmiles.debug D/Retrofit﹕ Content-Type: application/json
05-09 13:48:15.734    7053-7170/com.gmspartnersltd.earthmiles.debug D/Retrofit﹕ Transfer-Encoding: chunked
05-09 13:48:15.734    7053-7170/com.gmspartnersltd.earthmiles.debug D/Retrofit﹕ Connection: keep-alive
05-09 13:48:15.734    7053-7170/com.gmspartnersltd.earthmiles.debug D/Retrofit﹕ Vary: Accept, Cookie
05-09 13:48:15.735    7053-7170/com.gmspartnersltd.earthmiles.debug D/Retrofit﹕ X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
05-09 13:48:15.735    7053-7170/com.gmspartnersltd.earthmiles.debug D/Retrofit﹕ Allow: GET, HEAD, OPTIONS
05-09 13:48:15.735    7053-7170/com.gmspartnersltd.earthmiles.debug D/Retrofit﹕ OkHttp-Selected-Protocol: http/1.1
05-09 13:48:15.735    7053-7170/com.gmspartnersltd.earthmiles.debug D/Retrofit﹕ OkHttp-Sent-Millis: 1431193695653
05-09 13:48:15.735    7053-7170/com.gmspartnersltd.earthmiles.debug D/Retrofit﹕ OkHttp-Received-Millis: 1431193695733
05-09 13:48:15.735    7053-7170/com.gmspartnersltd.earthmiles.debug D/Retrofit﹕ {"detail": "Authentication credentials were not provided."}
05-09 13:48:15.735    7053-7170/com.gmspartnersltd.earthmiles.debug D/Retrofit﹕ <--- END HTTP (59-byte body)
```

### RestClient

```
public class EMRestClient {

    private static EMRestInterface mEMRestService;




    public static EMRestInterface getmEMRestService() {

        if (mEMRestService == null) {
            Gson gson = new GsonBuilder()
                    .setExclusionStrategies(new ExclusionStrategy() {
                        @Override
                        public boolean shouldSkipField(FieldAttributes f) {
                            return f.getDeclaringClass().equals(RealmObject.class);
                        }

                        @Override
                        public boolean shouldSkipClass(Class<?> clazz) {
                            return false;
                        }
                    })

                    .registerTypeAdapter(Date.class, new DateSerializer())

                    .setFieldNamingPolicy(FieldNamingPolicy.LOWER_CASE_WITH_UNDERSCORES)    // converts 'short_description' in JSON to shortDescription, java style
                    .create();



            RestAdapter restAdapter = new RestAdapter.Builder()
                    .setEndpoint(App.BASE_URL)                // sets base url
                    .setRequestInterceptor(new AuthTokenHeaderInterceptor())        // provides Authorization : Token XYZ header if required
                    .setLogLevel(RestAdapter.LogLevel.FULL)                         // logs all input and output request/response for debug
                    .setConverter(new GsonConverter(gson))                          // provides additional conversion functions from json if reqd
                    .build();

            mEMRestService = restAdapter.create(EMRestInterface.class);
        }

        return mEMRestService;
    }
}
```

### The Interceptor for injecting the authorization header is :

```
public class AuthTokenHeaderInterceptor implements RequestInterceptor {
    @Override
    public void intercept(RequestFacade request) {


        request.addHeader("Screen-Width", String.valueOf(App.SCREEN_WIDTH));
        request.addHeader("Screen-Height", String.valueOf(App.SCREEN_HEIGHT));
        request.addHeader("Screen-Density", String.valueOf(App.SCREEN_DENSITY));
        request.addHeader("Screen-Scaled-Density", String.valueOf(App.SCREEN_SCALED_DENSITY));
        request.addHeader("Screen-Density-DPI", String.valueOf(App.SCREEN_DENSITY_DPI));
        request.addHeader("Device-Type", App.DEVICE_TYPE);
        request.addHeader("App-Version", App.APP_VERSION);

        if (App.getLoginData()!=null) {
            String authToken = App.getLoginData().getAuthToken();
            if (!authToken.equals("")) {
                String authTokenString = "Token " + authToken;
                request.addHeader("Authorization", authTokenString);
            }
        }


    }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried to debug in your if statements to see if you are adding the header? It seems that the code might not be adding it. I would remove the if statements and add the header and verify with retrofit logging what the header value is being set too.